# Apply id of newly created room object as a field in another new room object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

What i am trying to do is create two database entries, one immediately after the other

I want to use the id from the first entry as a field in the second entry in a different table.

I am inserting the product using a coroutine, the product.id is autogenerated by room.

Then on the next line after the coroutine is complete calling createPricePoint

In createPricePoint I am setting the itemId using the id from product and then inserting the price point into a table using a coroutine

E.g.
Product.id = Int

Price.productId = Product.id

Does anyone know how I should do this.

Thank you

View Model

```
@HiltViewModel
class AddProductViewModel
@Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {

    val newProduct = repository.getMostRecentProduct().asLiveData()

    fun addNewItem(name: String, price: String, shop: String, date: String) {
        if (isProductValid(name, price, shop, date)) {
            addNewProduct(name, price, shop, date)
        }
    }

    private fun addNewPrice(name: String, price: String, shop: String, date: String, newProductItemId: Int) {
        val newPrice = Price(name = name, price = price.toDouble(), date = date, itemId = newProductItemId)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insertPrice(newPrice)
        }
    }

    private fun addNewProduct(name: String, price: String, shop: String, date: String) {
        val newProductInput = Product(name = name, currentPrice = price.toDouble(), shop = shop, priceDate = date, favourite = 0)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insertProduct(newProductInput)
            }
        Log.d("id", "${newProduct.value?.itemId ?: 1}")
        addNewPrice(name,price, shop, date, newProduct.value!!.itemId)
    }


    private fun isProductValid(
        name: String,
        price: String,
        shop: String,
        date: String
    ): Boolean {
        var formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
        formatter.isLenient = false

        if (name.isBlank() || price.isBlank() || shop.isBlank() || date.isBlank()) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Fragment (has a date picker)

```
package com.benshapiro.pricekeeper.ui.Add

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import com.benshapiro.pricekeeper.databinding.AddProductFragmentBinding
import com.benshapiro.pricekeeper.utils.DatePickerFragment
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class AddProductFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: AddProductFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val viewModel: AddProductViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = AddProductFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.newProduct.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner){ product ->
            product.let {
                val currentId = viewModel.newProduct.value?.itemId ?: 0
                if (currentId != viewModel.newProduct.value?.itemId ?: 0) {
                    Log.d("old id", "$currentId")
                    Log.d("id", "${viewModel.newProduct.value?.itemId ?: 1}")
                }
            }

        }

        binding.apply {
            selectDateBtn.setOnClickListener {
                val datePickerFragment = DatePickerFragment()
                val supportFragmentManager = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager

                supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
                    "REQUEST_KEY", viewLifecycleOwner
                ) { resultKey, bundle ->
                    if (resultKey == "REQUEST_KEY") {
                        val date = bundle.getString("SELECTED_DATE")
                        Log.d("date", "$date")
                        itemDate.setText(date)
                    }
                }
                datePickerFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "DatePickerFragment")
            }
            saveAction.setOnClickListener {
                viewModel.addNewItem(
                    itemName.text.toString(),
                    itemPrice.text.toString(),
                    itemShop.text.toString(),
                    itemDate.text.toString()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repository

```
class Repository
@Inject constructor(
    private val priceDao: PriceDao,
    private val productDao: ProductDao,
    private val priceDatabase: PriceDatabase
) {
    fun getProductsList(query: String, sortOrder: SortOrder) : Flow<List<Product>> {
        return productDao.getProductList(query, sortOrder)
    }
    suspend fun insertProduct(product: Product) {
        productDao.insert(product)
    }
    suspend fun updateProduct(product: Product) {
        productDao.update(product)
    }
    fun getMostRecentProduct() : Flow<Product> {
        return productDao.getMostRecentProduct()
    }

    fun getPriceHistory(itemId: Int) {
        priceDao.searchDatabase(itemId)
    }
    suspend fun updatePrice(price: Price) {
        priceDao.update(price)
    }
    suspend fun insertPrice(price: Price) {
        priceDao.insert(price)
    }
}
```

Comment: Product.id is autogenerated

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added the code, just to be clear, what I am trying to do is insert a product and then use the itemId from the product as the itemId for the price (that way I can later on link them together in some form)